# Mockito-Android Testar retorno do método

Tags: java, android, testes-de-unidade, mockito

Estou tentando testar um retorno de um método da minha classe em um projeto Android. Estou fazendo desta maneira:

```
MyClass var = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class);
```

Com isto, eu já tenho minha instância. Agora eu preciso testar métodos desta minha classe, eu fiz desta maneira:

```
Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(var).loadTexture("back.png")
```

O retorno está sempre vindo null. Porém a imagem existe e não era para estar retornando null...

Comment: tente Mockito.when(var.loadTexture("back.png")).thenCallRealMethod() e fala se acontece algo.

Comment: O teste passa com sucesso independente do valor que eu passo no `loadTexture("blablabla");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está tentando testar uma classe "Mockada", ou seja, você não está testando a classe real e sim uma instancia "default" dela. Por isso que quando você dá `loadTexture()` é retornado `null`.

Os mocks devem ser utilizados para representar objetos externos e que são necessários para a execução de métodos de uma classe. Por exemplo:

```
public class MinhaClasseA{

    private MinhaClasseB mcB;

    public MinhaClasseA(MinhaClasseB mcB){

        this.mcB = mcB
    }

    public int fazAlgumaCoisa(){

        return mcB.fazOutraCoisa();
    }
}

public class MinhaClasseB{

    public int fazOutraCoisa(){

        return 10;
    }
}
```

Nesse caso, percebe-se que a classe A tem uma dependecia da classe B, portanto, se você quisesse testar a classe A, você teria que criar um Mock da classe B e explicitar quais valores ela retorna, ou seja, você diria o comportamento da classe B e depois você verificaria se o a classe A age corretamente conforme recebe os dados de B.

Exemplo:

```
MinhaClasseB mcBMock = Mockito.mock(MinhaClasseB.class);
MinhaClasseA mcA = new MinhaClasseA(mcBMock);

int intMock = 10;

when(mcBMock.fazOutraCoisa()).thenReturn(intMock);

assertEquals(mcA.fazAlgumaCoisa(),intMock);
```

Nesse caso, você está dizendo que quando o método `fazOutraCoisa()` de B for chamado, ele deve retornar 10 para quem o chamou ( a classe A). Portanto ao usar o `assertEquals` você quer saber se a classe A realmente está recebendo o valor de retorno do método `fazOutraCoisa` de B.